# How to refresh $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this code update every 1 minute?

```
$.getJSON('/stats/rest/service.php/network/status', function(result) {
    $("#currentusers").text(result.users.val);
});
```

Comment: setTimeout() or setInterval()?

Comment: I wrapped it in `setTimeout()` but it doesn't update the button text?

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
  $.getJSON('/stats/rest/service.php/network/status', function(result) {
      $("#currentusers").text(result.users.val);
  });
}, (1000*60)*1 ); // change '1' to however many minutes
```